# Only applying XSLT template if a template with the given mode exists

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

In my site's master XSLT template I have:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/data" mode="page-scripts"/>
```

On another page that imports the above master stylesheet, I have a template that inserts some JavaScript:

```
<xsl:template match="/data" mode="page-scripts">
    <!-- JavaScript -->
</xsl:template>
```

On pages that don't have the above template, the contents of the `data` node is output according to the default template.

What would be a good way to avoid this without having to have a blank template that matches the `page-scripts` mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On pages that don't have the above template, the contents of the data
>   node is output according to the default template.
>
> What would be a good way to avoid this without having to have a blank
>   template that matches the page-scripts mode?

There is no way to prevent the XSLT built-in templates from being selected for execution, except by overriding them.

A good solution is to place the "blank" overriding template in the "master" stylesheet itself, thus avoiding the need to add any such templates in any of the importing stylesheets.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I've just found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577606/xslt-apply-template-with-mode-incorrect-result-with-no-matching-mode).

I had to put `<xsl:template match="*" mode="page-scripts"/>` in my master stylesheet to override the default template.